# Clear Constants in a range without clearing references and formulas

Tags: vba, excel, constants, formulas

I am trying to clear all the number constants in a range of cells without clearing any formulas or cell references.  Clearing the constants from cells without any formulas or cell references is simple but I am having trouble doing it when those are present.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
Range("B2:B11").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

In this range cells B5 and B7 have formulas with cell references as follows:

B5: =(G83*H1)+1181.05

B7: =E33+1292.76

The cell references will also at times reference cells on other sheets in the same workbook.  I need to clear the constants from these formulas while leaving the references intact.

Comment: You are asking for a way to parse all the formulas in a sheet and remove any literal values in the formula?  For example, `=A1+10` you wish to remove the `+10`  and you want to do similar for all the formulas in a sheet?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove '+1181' and '+1292.76' ?

Comment: Yes, but I only want to remove it from this range.  I'll want to do it across about 36 sheets but the range will be the same on each sheet.

Comment: I'll offer a solution with Split() if desired, otherwise I'd suggest a [For each s in sheets...] as an edit to paul bica's to handle all sheets in a workbook, and including the appropriate range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove constants from all formulas in current workbook based on 2 patterns:

- `"=Formula-[Space]-`**`PlusSign`**`-[Space]-Constant"` (space optional)

  - `=(G83*H1)+1181.05 or =(G83*H1) +1181.05 or =(G83*H1)+ 1181.05` becomes **`=(G83*H1)`**
  - `=E33+1292.76 or =E33 +1292.76 or =E33+ 1292.76 or =E33 + 1292.76` becomes **`=E33`**
- `"=Formula-[Space]-`**`MinusSign`**`-[Space]-Constant"` (space optional)

---

```
Public Sub clearConstantsFromWorkBookFormulas()
    Const PATTERNS As String = "~+*|~+ *|~ +*| ~+ *|~-*|~- *|~ -*|~ - *"
    Dim pat As Variant

    For Each pat In Split(PATTERNS, "|")
        Cells.Replace What:=pat, _
                      Replacement:=vbNullString, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      MatchCase:=False
    Next

End Sub
```

---

.

This is a more generic option using regEx pattern matching and arrays:

```
Public Sub testClear()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        removeConstantsFromFormulas ws.Range("B2:B11"), getRegEx
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub removeConstantsFromFormulas(ByRef rng As Range, ByRef regEx As Object)
    Dim v As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long

    lr = rng.Rows.Count
    lc = rng.Columns.Count

    If lr > 0 And lc > 0 Then

        v = rng.Formula
        For r = 1 To lr
           For c = 1 To lc
              If Left(v(r, c), 1) = "=" Then
                 If regEx.Test(v(r, c)) Then v(r, c) = regEx.Replace(v(r, c), vbNullString)
              End If
           Next
        Next
        rng.Formula = v

    End If
End Sub

Private Function getRegEx() As Object
    Set getRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    getRegEx.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z][0-9]+(\.?[0-9]+)"
    getRegEx.Global = True
    getRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
End Function
```

---

RegEx pattern: one or more digits, digit group not preceded by a letter, with or without a fraction part

Comment: What if the literal is BEFORE the reference, like `=10+A1`. What about all the other operators `- * / &` ? What about literal parameters to functions? Perhaps your solution will work for the asker, but not in the more interesting general case.

Comment: @ExcelHero: I provided a solution for the requirement presented; it can be extrapolated based on particular need: for `=10+A1` change search pattern to `*+`, or create a Select Case for the 4 basic math operators as required. The answer though, addresses the only pattern posted :) (show one of the ways to approach the problem)

Comment: No need to answer, it was rhetorical. I suspect though that to do this properly in the general case is not trivial and cannot be accomplished with an extrapolation. It requires complete parsing and a bunch of heuristics, and is likely not doable for parameters.

Comment: @paulbica the tricky part with parsing formula rather than the constant is that you need to cope with the absolute and relative reference combinations as well.

Comment: @brettdj - good point! the pattern in regex will be a bit easier to adjust to something like `[^a-zA-Z$][0-9]...` (I haven't tested it though)

Answer (score 0):

This attempt should handle most examples using a Regexp.

There may be some edge cases as the discussion above points out. For the code below

> =(G83*H1)+1181.05
>   =10+A1
>   =A1+10
>   =A1+(10)
>   =A1+10.0

becomes

> =(G83*H1)
>   =+A1
>   =A1
>   =A1
>   =A1

I note it would also take out the *^2* in `=A1^2`

It clearly also won't cater for named formulae (named ranges).

*Updated: Now handles cascading parentheses, ie*

> =A1+(27+(11-2))

becomes

> =A1

```
Sub Format()
Dim objRegexB As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim X

X = [b2:b11].Formula

Set RegExB = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegExB
    .Pattern = "[=\+\/\*^\-](\([0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?\)|[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)"
   .Global = True
    For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
        Do While .Test(X(lngCnt, 1))
           X(lngCnt, 1) = .Replace(X(lngCnt, 1), vbNullString)
        Loop
    Next
End With
[b2:b11].Formula = X

End Sub
```